# passing a '+' sign within a JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable that may contain a '+" sign within, But after passing in the next page it is getting concatenated.

let say i pass '2+2' , from first.php to second.php on second.php it appears as '2 2'.But I need it as '2+2' only. The same is correctly working for '2-2'. This is my **first.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub").click(function() {
 var txt1 = $("#userquery").val(); //textbox value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "second.php",
            cache: false,
            data: "txt1=" + txt1,    
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(result) {
                $("#sqlresult").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>    
<textarea  id='userquery'  rows='5' cols='115' spellcheck='false' wrap='off' placeholder='Write SQL query here..'></textarea>
<input id='sub' type='submit'   value='Execute' title='Ctrl+Enter'>
<hr><div id='sqlresult'><?php include('second.php'); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a string for `data`, which means you're taking responsibility for it being properly encoded (but not properly encoding it). It happens that in URI encoding, `+` means space.

Just pass it as an object and jQuery will handle properly encoding it for you:

```
data: {txt1: txt1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must just url encode your value before passing it like a url parameter

```
var txt1 = encodeURIComponent($("#userquery").val());
```

Answer (score -1):

*try like this*

```
"text"+ '+' + "text2"
```